# Defining a two-variable-function from values

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, graphing-functions, math-software

I have a set of values for the function $f(x,y)$. I can now simply draw it but i need an approximative function that describes my values (more or less) accurate. Is there such thing like a software solution to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Comment: Do you have an intuition about the general trend your data points follow? If so you can fit a model to describe them

Comment: I have a function for every z-value that describes the belonging y-x correlation

Comment: There are two ways for this: Guessing a function that describes the behaviour, as @caverac suggested, and then fitting the model to your data. Or by [2D interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation). Algorithms for both ways can be found in packages of every language, e.g. Scipy for Python.